# [Swing]Add same label to different location in a panel, without copying

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I have an application calculating clock-in hours of all seven days in a week. What I plan, is to let users introduce entry and leaving hours/minutes of every day, and thus collect these data to do calculation.

The UI part should be like:

```
Monday:     mondayEntryHour   :   mondayEntryMinutes       mondayLeaveHour   :   mondayLeaveMinutes        
Tuesday:   tuesdayEntryHour   :   tuesdayEntryMinutes     tuesdayLeaveHour   :   tuesdayLeaveMinutes
....
```

All where I collect data, are `JTextFields`, and the `:` between them, is a `JLabel`. All 14 labels have same content, same font and style, but I just cannot create a same variable and add it 14 times in all where needed to be, because it is added only the last time.

To prove what I say, I have a SCCEE here:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class RepeatedJLabel extends JFrame {
    public RepeatedJLabel() {
        run();

    }

    public void run() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug, fill", "[grow]", "[]10[]10[]"));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("MY LABEL 1");
        p.add(label, "cell 0 1, grow");
        p.add(label, "cell 0 2, grow");
        p.add(label, "cell 0 3, grow");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        getContentPane().add(p);

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                RepeatedJLabel test = new RepeatedJLabel();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Must I create 14 variables for them? It is stupid. I don't wanna mingle with copy/shallow copy/deep copy of this variable, because it's too simply to mess around. Any idea?

Comment: Create a factory method and call it in a loop.

Comment: And you appear to be confusing variable with object. Yes you do need 14 JLabel objects, but you certainly don't need 14 JLabel variables.

Comment: ........... and I'm wondering if a JTable wouldn't work best for this particular situation....

Comment: Yes you are right, I got confused in object and variables. 14 variables point to one object is the problem here. Factory is good, loop is not so good as it: the cells where I want to add them have different col and row indexes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"I'm wondering if a JTable wouldn't work best for this particular situation"* Looking at the data as shown by the OP, a `JTable` was the first thing I thought of..

Comment: `"Factory is good, loop is not so good as it: the cells where I want to add them have different col and row indexes."` -- Which could be the parameters of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a [factory method](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21) to create each `JLabel`:

   ```
   private static JLabel newLabel() {
       return new JLabel("MY LABEL 1");
   }
   ```
2. Use a `for` loop to add the `JLabel` each time:

   ```
   final int amountOfLabels = 3;
   for(int i = 0; i < amountOfLabels; i++) {
       panel.add(newLabel(), "cell 0 " + i + ", grow");
   }
   ```

Comment: At last it's the way I adopted. Easy to integrate. And, if we need more parameters, change this method and done.